# Still getting game requests from a person I have deleted as a friend

Tags: facebook

I have recently deleted an old friend from Facebook but I am still getting requests for lives etc from her for games. I have tried using Facebook privacy settings which will let me block her from seeing any of my feeds but it won’t accept blocking her from sending me game requests we both play. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this for games you both play?